# Delete a folder under VisualSVN Server on windows 7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

*[I would like to delete a folder from the VisualSVN Server.]*

I have a repository with multiple folders in it. Now, I would like to delete one particular folder from it. When I try to delete it, I get an error message like "Cannot verify lock on <-Some path->. No username available".

I implemented several other solution provided on stackoverflow like "stealing lock", making all files and folder read only. However still I am not able to delete the folder.

I have been trying this for past 4 hours now and going crazy doing it. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a stale lock in the repository (aka "zombie lock").

If you know a path to the stale lock, then you can remove it using [`svnadmin rmlocks`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/rmlocks/) command. You should run the command on the machine where VisualSVN Server is installed and pass the path to repository of filesystem and the locked path. The command should look like:

```
svnadmin rmlocks <path-to-repository> "<path-to-file>"
```

You can use [`svnadmin lslocks`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/lslocks/) tool to find out files locked in Subversion repository.

Learn more about locking in Subversion by reading [SVNBook | Locking](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/locking/).